# Combine Three mySQL queries into one and return one JSON object

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I have these three queries:

```
$sql = "select count(distinct f_home) as home_count_total from cr_test;" ;

$sql2 = "select distinct f_home, count(f_home) as home_count from cr_test group by f_home;" ;
```

//pseudocode below

```
$sql3 = "select distinct f_home, round(count(f_home)/<home_count_total  FROM FIRST QUERY>*100,2) as CountOf from cr_test group by f_home;" ;
```

What I need is one json object (which I can get via PDO, so don't worry about that) with three pieces of data per entry: f_home, home_count, and CountOf.

How can I combine these into one query so I can return one JSON object?

Comment: Looks like you need to learn sub-queries.

Comment: Pretend I don't know anything about this...can you get me started? I've looked at the documentation, but can't seem to figure out how to apply to my case.

Comment: Perhaps you can setup a SQL fiddle and give us a link to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with this query:

```
SELECT 
  f_home, 
  COUNT(f_home) AS home_count,
  ROUND(COUNT(f_home) / home_count_total * 100, 2) AS CountOf
FROM 
  cr_test,
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT f_home) AS home_count_total FROM cr_test) t
GROUP BY f_home
```